# Steps to hardening JBoss for production use on Windows?

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, configuration, jboss

Looking for resources/guidance on hardening a JBoss installation on windows for production use.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you are using Jboss in a standard N-tier configuration.

(1) Harden Windows 
http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/stig/windows_server_2008_security_guide.pdf
http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/stig/win2k-XP-03-vista-addendumv6r1-052107.doc

(2) Harden Jboss 
http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/stig/application-services-stig-v1r1.pdf

Remember to address the embedded Tomcat via the Application services STIG

(3) Harden associated Webservers 
http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/stig/Web-Server-STIG-V6R1.pdf

(4) Harden associated Databases 
http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/stig/database-stig-v8r1.zip

(5) Consider Defense in Depth
Add maybe a web application firewall http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Application_Firewall

Below are some suggestions for your network

(6) Add a file integrity tool such as Samhain or Tripwire

(7) Ensure you have syslog enabled, going to a syslog server, with Splunk looking  at everything.

(8) Use a network intrusion detection system, maybe something in an easy package to run like Security Onion.  Connect it to your syslog and Splunk

Answer (score 0):

You don't state the JBoss version nor what the server will be doing nor if it will be facing the web, so there's not much we can tell.

Basically you should start by removing all the services you don't need. You can find some guidance [here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SlimmingJBossAS43). The idea is that you need to remove everything except what's really necessary.

If the server will be web facing, block all ports but the ones you need (80 probably). Also, probably not a good idea to run as admin!